# Bitcoin wallet in Rust

Tags: wallet, development, rust-bitcoin

Could not find any resources on how to build a simple bitcoin wallet in Rust? Please share some relevant resources or repositories.

Answer (score 0):

> Please share some relevant resources or repositories.

1. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+wallet+rust)
2. [Questions on bitcoin.stackexchange that are tagged "rust-bitcoin"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust-bitcoin)

Answer (score 0):

- rust-bitcoin GitHub: https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-bitcoin
- Rust Book: Comprehensive guide to Rust programming.
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/
- Bitcoin Developer Guide: Understand
  the fundamentals of how Bitcoin works.
  https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/index.html