# Bitcoin Transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cli

How to code a Bitcoin transaction, including the address creation feature in Rust ? Which crates we have to use? Any blogs or resources would be very helpful

Comment: Sorry, I don’t really use rust, so I don’t have a good answer to provide. Have you had a look at the [`bitcoin`](https://crates.io/crates/bitcoin) crate? You could also take a look at [`bdk`](https://crates.io/crates/bdk).

Comment: if you have resources in some other language, you can share them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin wallet in Rust](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/122152/bitcoin-wallet-in-rust)

Comment: Looking at this again, your question is unreasonable broad. What have you tried so far, what _concrete_ issue are you stuck on? Imagine you are meeting a colleague at the water cooler, they have a good understanding of Bitcoin, but no idea what you have been working on. What context would you provide to get them in the picture?